Deriving a multiple based on actuals and forecast values
For context, we are using the DeepAR model for demand planning forecasting. Currently the forecast often underrepresents actual demand. It was suggested that we use a higher quantile to overestimate demand. Although, I believe we should not swing to far in the other direction so my assessment is that we should have the forecast exceeds actual demand but only if its no less than some multiple times the actual demand. Let me know if this is clear.
Now, I need to somehow come up with this multiple using numbers. As a first step I calculated the absolute difference between the forecast and actual amount, then I can get some metrics like mean, median absolute deviation, and standard deviation which are
mean:  10661.739321234914
median absolute deviation:  181.05746332806666
standard deviation:  391088.08675914136

I am a bit stuck on what I should do to formulate a multiple to use. I was thinking of just using 1.5 or 2 as the multiple but I need to quantify my reasoning otherwise its just pulling it out of thin air. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

To be honest, I indeed do not understand "we should have the forecast exceeds actual demand but only if its no less than some multiple times the actual demand". Can you clarify? Also, by "the forecast often underrepresents actual demand" do you mean an actual bias? All point forecasts will both under- and overestimate "many" demands, simply because of residual variation. Are you tailoring your forecasting methodology to the subsequent decisions to be taken based on the forecast? If these are target stock settings, then you should indeed be calculating quantile forecasts.

@StephanKolassa The current forecast is using a 0.6 quantile and this is causing the under estimate. In demand forecasting, it is better to overestimate as it can cause a supply shock to our customer to fulfill the actual demand. What I am trying to say is that I want to make sure we satisfy the cases where the forecast exceeds demand but no greater than some threshold, does that make more sense?

Hm. I happen to be doing demand forecasting. My recommended procedure would be to set a target service level and then forecast an appropriate quantile forecast. The problem here is (a) there are many different definitions of a "service level", and the "right" one will depend on your business, and (b) you should really aim for a cost-optimal forecast, which is a different thing than pulling a target service level out of your hat. ...

... In any case, I don't quite see the point of requiring that the quantile forecast not exceed actual demand by more than some multiple. Whether this is even possible depends hugely on your actual demand: if you have zero observations, this is not even mathematically possible, and if you have large spikes (driven, e.g., by promotions, or quarter-end incentives, or calendar events), this may again not be possible. And in any case, the entire requirement looks very ad-hoc. Much better to look at downstream consequences of a forecast and analyze stocks and out-of-stocks.

@StephanKolassa Would it be possible to have a chat? You seem like an you have more experience then me so would love to explain further to get your thoughts. I added you on LinkedIn.

Sure. LinkedIn would be easiest. I don't see an invite that looks like you, did I decline you? If so, just reach out again (if LI allows that?), ideally invest a few words so I don't decline again - I get far too many invites from unknowns.
